# Group theory with grep?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ho.history-overview, geometric-group-theory, automata-theory

While reading Bill Thurston's [obituary](http://www.ams.org/publications/journals/notices/201601/rnoti-p31.pdf) in the Notices of the AMS I came across the following fascinating anecdote (pg. 32):

> Bill’s enthusiasm during the early stages of mathematical discovery was infectious. Once, while sitting in his
> living room, Bill said to me, “I can do this group with
> grep,” which was sort of strange to hear at first. But being
> his student I knew just enough computerese to have an
> inkling of what he was saying: he was able to compute
> in that group with the UNIX utility for processing regular
> expressions using finite deterministic automata. From
> there, it was exciting to observe the quick unfolding of
> the theory of automatic groups.

Looking through David Epstein's *Word Processing in Groups* I can see that there are indeed connections between [automatic groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_group) and regular expressions that should allow faster algorithms for certain computations e.g. solving the word problem.

But is there a concrete example of a group-theoretic computation with `grep`?

Comment: *grep* can test whether a word is in canonical form for some groups, eg the free group on $a,b$ modulo $a^3=b^4=1$, $ba=ab^2$ — but I hope that Thurston saw something more impressive.

Comment: The remarkable thing here is not so much that ``grep`` can be used to compute regular expresssions; but that regular expressions (which are equivalent in computing power to finite automata) can be used to compute in groups! An automatic group is in essence a group which (1) has a regular set of representatives for its elements; and (2) a finite automaton for each letter $a$ in the generating set, which simulates what "right multiplying by $a$" does to each representative. Some finite number of automata -- and you can completely describe the word problem of the group! [cont...]

Comment: [contd.] So the fact that many infinite groups, in which the word problem can be quite non-trivial to solve at first glance (e.g. hyperbolic groups, Braid groups), turn out to be automatic, and can hence be computed with using only some fixed set of regular expressions (in ``grep``, or wherever) is the remarkable fact to me. A specific implementation in ``grep`` is then more or less trivial to write out, given the finite state automata. There are many explicit such automata in *Word Processing*. I'm sure Derek Holt will have a lot more nuance to add to this -- let's hope he sees this question.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda, can you give an example of a group and an “implementation in *grep*”? I think *grep* usually needs to go inside a loop, in general a loop whose bounds can’t be computed recursively, and that doesn’t sound like what Thurston was describing.

Comment: @MattF. I'm not sure what you mean by "go inside a loop", so perhaps I'm missing some subtlety. I probably couldn't do it explicitly, as I'm not savvy with automatic groups or ``grep``, but here's a sample pseudo-code; the rest is just finding the multiplying automata (which can be done by "hand"): we want to check if $w \in A^\ast$ is accepted by an automaton $H$. Write down the regex $r$ for $H$. Then put $w$ in a text-file, called ``w.txt``. Then run ``grep r w.txt``. Then $H$ accepts $w$ iff the output is non-empty.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda Yes I've seen the question, and I heard about Thurston's use of grep very early in the development of the theory. But I think he only used grep in an attempt to recognize words in normal form in some typical examples. Solving the word problem involves reducing the word to normal form letter by letter, and I don't believe that can be done with grep alone. Note also that solving the word problem in automatic groups using this method is quadratic time, whereas in theory it can be solved in linear time in hyperbolic groups using the Dehn algorithm, but ...

Comment: except in some well understood example, like surface groups, and groups satisfying strong small cancellation properties, the Dehn algorithm is more difficult to implement, because it requires knowing the constant $\delta$ of hyperbolicity, and also all relations of total length up to $4\delta$ (or it might be $8\delta$).

Comment: I am the author of that quote. I vaguely remember during that time looking over Bill's shoulder at his computer screen while he did some of those calculations. Be that as it may, here's a followup question for @DerekHolt: Does your software allow the user to, in some sense, output the word recognition automaton and the multiplier automata for an automatic structure on a group? If so, there are other algorithms which could convert those automata into regular expressions, allowing one to use grep.

Comment: Of course, this is bass-ackwards, because the regular expression can be much more complicated than the automaton; my understanding is that most of what grep does is to immediately convert the regular expression into an automaton. I'm confident that all Bill needed was a few simple examples to spur him on to the recognition of regular languages and FDAs as useful tools in group theory, and ultimately as the basis of a new theory.

Comment: @Lee Mosher yes the programs output all of these automata to files. A long time ago I did experiment with programs to find equivalent regular expressions for finite state automata, but they typically came up with horrifically long and unreadable results, even for apparently simple examples like the free gorup of rank 2. In fact it is a nice exercise to produce a shortish regular expression for the set of reduced words.

Comment: @LeeMosher - that really sounds like an answer to the question, and not just a comment… hint, hint. :)

Answer (score 21):

I wrote that quote, and I'll take the [hint of @SamNead](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420294/group-theory-with-grep#comment1079616_420294) and try to write an answer, although the best I can do is to write a somewhat speculative extension of the story behind the quote, laced with some mathematical musings.

From my memories of that period (sometime in the mid-late 1980's), I only vaguely recall looking at any actual output of Bill Thurston's computer experiments using grep to compute in groups. My memory is not at all precise enough regarding any actual examples he might have produced, but I suspect that they must have been pretty simple examples, for the following reasons.

In the theory of regular languages and FDAs (finite deterministic automata), there are reasonably simple algorithms for going back and forth between regular expressions and finite deterministic automata, producing an expression matching exactly the words accepted by a given automaton, and producing an automaton accepting exactly the words matched by a given expression. The algorithm from regular expressions to FDAs works pretty efficiently and is the basis of the **grep** utility. The algorithm from FDAs to regular expressions seems to be horribly inefficient, as reported by Derek Holt in [his comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420294/group-theory-with-grep#comment1079534_420294). So one might expect that writing an actual regular expression that matches normal forms for a certain group could be quite tedious.

Nonetheless if one is clever enough one can sometimes just manually come up with a regular expression to match a given language. See the exercise Derek Holt suggests in [his comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420294/group-theory-with-grep#comment1079534_420294); carrying out that exercise will likely give you the most direct answer to your question.

I suspect that this is what Thurston was doing during this discovery period: noticing that certain finitely generated groups have a regular language of normal forms.

Thurston was also very familiar with concepts of cone types (developed by Jim Cannon around that time; Thurston and Cannon talked together a lot during that period). So at some point during this process he certainly also noticed the connections between cone types and what we now call the 2-tape "multiplier automata" which are at the heart of the theory of automatic groups. It is tempting to speculate whether Thurston's **grep** experiments extended to writing regular expressions for 2-tape multiplier automata, but honestly I have no idea.

Comment: Perhaps whomever (Dylan?j got Thurston’s computer files could take a look for such, if any, examples. But I understand that that is a big ask. Hmm.

Comment: Curious: What is a cone type?

Comment: The cone $C(g)$ of a group element $g$ is all elements $h$ such that some geodesic from the identity to $h$ passes through $g$. The cone type of $g$ is the orbit of $C(g)$ under the action of $G$ on its power set (by left multiplication).

Answer (score 5):

As Derek Holt suggested in a comment, it seems Thurston was indeed thinking of word acceptors that returned normal forms for elements of automatic groups. From a 1989 research report of his titled [Groups, tilings and finite state automata:](http://timo.jolivet.free.fr/docs/ThurstonLectNotes.pdf) (pg. 41)

> A good example is the Unix utility `egrep`. The word acceptor for Z, for instance, could
> be specified by the regular expression
> `a*|A*`
> where the symbol `*` denotes zero or more repetitions of the preceding object,
> and the
> symbol `|` means ‘or’. The command `egrep '^a*|A*$'`
> prints out all lines of its inputs which are accepted by WA $\dots$

He goes on in page 42:

> For instance, a word acceptor which accepts only words in reduced form for
> the free group $\langle ab|\rangle$ is illustrated in 11.3. The corresponding `egrep` command is
> `egrep '^(b+|B+)?((a+|A+)(b+|B+))*(a+|A+)?$'` $\dots$

With a text file as input one can easily check that these commands are the correct word acceptors.